# How to overwrite an internal function call with a decorator?

Tags: python, overloading, decorator

I have a function like this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
def mysin(x):
    return math.sin(x)
```

Now this is nice, but I want to modify the function such that instead of calling math.sin, it uses numpy.sin. My try was this

```
def replace_math_with_numpy(func):
    math = np
    return func
```

However, this does not work: `replace_math_with_numpy(mysin)([0.1,0.2])` returns an error indicating that my decorator has not worked. Why did it not work, and how can I fix my decorator - or is this not possible?

Edit: I want to avoid modifying mysin, as in reality this is just a MWE, and mysin is a library function with many calls and it would very tedious to manually replace all of them while running the function.

Comment: Why do you have a function just to call another function? @Ewoud

Comment: Technically you can use `patch` for this, but that's kind of horrible -- like @Vishnudev said it doesn't make sense to have this extra layer of indirection in the first place.  Maybe you could provide more context about the problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @Vishnudev This is a simplified minimal example. In reality my function is much more complex.

Comment: Could the "real" version of your function simply use dependency injection?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using `numpy` rather than `math`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to patch @Samwise, that does look like it does what I need. I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with dependency injection, I'll read up about it a bit more.

Comment: The broader problem is that I want to flexibly replace some module with others - e.g. math with numpy - but only in a few functions (not all), and flexibly - so that the user can disable it - this enable/disable check could be done in the decorator then.

Comment: What you'd typically do in real code where you might want to apply different functions, rather than using `patch`, would be to have the function accept the other function as an argument.  It doesn't really make sense in your example because your example function doesn't do anything other than call the one other function.

Answer (score 2):

Just send an argument to the function to indicate library to use

```
import math
import numpy as np

def mysin(x, engine='math'):
    if engine == 'math':
        return math.sin(x)
    elif engine == 'numpy':
        return np.sin(x)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(mysin(30))
    print(mysin(30, engine='numpy'))
```

Comment: I agree with this approach, although to handle a more complex function, you can do `if engine=='math': import math as math; else: import numpy as math`

Comment: When you have different arguments for different libraries, this approach would help a lot. @Cargo23 What you have proposed would have serious problems of misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks, I hoped to avoid something like this - I edited my question a bit, sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can override a function in a module using setattr:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def replace_math_with_numpy(fName):
    setattr(math,fName,getattr(np,fName))


print(math.sin)                     # <built-in function sin>
replace_math_with_numpy("sin")
print(math.sin, math.sin == np.sin) # <ufunc 'sin'> True
```